# 3d image from glb file which "look at mouse" in ReactJS

Tags: reactjs, three.js, react-three-fiber

I've created my 3D image and exported in a .gbl file (let's say [this](https://downloadfree3d.com/3d-models/electronics/phone/iphone-14-pro/)) and now I'd like to use it in ReactJS. I tried to use [React Three Fiber](https://docs.pmnd.rs/react-three-fiber/getting-started/introduction) without success. I would like achieve a float effect [like this](https://codesandbox.io/s/imn42?file=/src/App.js:422-454) but I'd also like my 3D image follows the mouse cursor in the page ([something like that](https://sbcode.net/react-three-fiber/look-at-mouse/).

How can I achieve that result?